# Why doesn't JS complier recognize this call to Array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to figure out why my call to .prototype.filter is giving me a `TypeError: curr.filter is not a function`.

```
const intersection = (arrays) => {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return curr.filter(el => acc.includes(el));
  });
};

console.log(intersection([5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
```

To my understanding I am declaring a function `const intersection` which takes in `arrays` and then returns the result of calling `arrays.reduce` which 'reduces' the results of filtering the current value and creating a new array that includes all instances of accumulator `acc` including the current value `curr`.

Since filter creates a new array on runtime I figured this would work as is yet it does not. What am I not seeing?

Comment: `arrays` refers to your first array, it _isn't_ a 2d array of all the arrays you pass into your function. You can use `...arrays` to get an array of all arguments passed into `intersection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array `rest parameter` to get all parameter as an array. In the given code you are taking just first argument and ignoring the rest.

try this.

```js
const intersection = (...arrays) => {
    console.log("arrays: ", arrays);
    return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return curr.filter(el => acc.includes(el));
    });
  };
  console.log("Result:" , intersection([5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20]));
```